# All Controls Click event on form

Tags: vb.net, click, controls

Is there a simple way to Activate the form when any controls in the form is clicked like datagirdview, panel, menustrip, button, textbox, label, etc....

it happens that my project can show many different form and it's hard for me to activate one form when it's on the back of the active form. I need to clicked the border of the form to activate it.

Comment: Can you show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: But forms already work like that, just checked it, if you click on a button of any form, it activates the form. Maybe I misunderstood something, maybe you should clarify it. However, it seems that you should do something else differently, it sounds like a really bad GUI. For example, maybe you should use multiple tabs in one form instead of multiple forms.

Comment: What you are describing is the behaviour that I already get. Are you sure you don't already have some code running that is changing this behaviour?

Comment: I've tried to put a panel in the form then when the panel is clicked then I have a code me.activate but the problem is when the other control is clicked which is on the panel my code doesn't work what I want to do eh if the user click anything on the form it the form will be activated..

Comment: Check that there isn't some code that prevents the normal behavior you are describing - for example: is there any suspicious code in the WndProc method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely your problem arises because your form is MDI child.. you'll have to click the menu bar to activate the form.. but if you have a borderless form, clicking on controls wont activate the form.. again, this usually happens on MDI but it shouldnt happen on a regular winform.. unless you have other running events in the background that interferes with the process.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear at all, and I don't know what you are trying to archieve, but for executing something with a click event you have to add the handler for every control.

If you are declaring it not dinamically just:

```
Private Sub ControlsClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles Panel1.Click, Button1.Click, TextBox2.Click ' etc.
    Me.Activate 'Or Whatever
End Sub
```

You have to add the handler for each control. The same if you do it dinamically:

```
Private Sub InitializeClickHandlers(sender As Control, Optional bChilds As Boolean = True)
    For Each elem As Control In sender.Controls
        AddHandler elem.Click, AddressOf ControlsClick(elem, New EventArgs)

        If bChilds AndAlso elem.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            Call InitializeClickHandlers(sender)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then, for every control in the form, you call it like: `Call InitializeClickHandlers(Me)`
Or, for every control inside a panel: `Call InitializeClickHandlers(Panel1)`